# How to open a child frame in a single application window in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

What I want is when I click on a button a new window should get open and that window should be a child of the same main window, But what I am getting is a new Instance of a new window. How do I solve this in **tkinter**?

Here is the screenshot of what I do not want, Every time a new instance of window is getting is created, I want to make a child instance of same main window:

[image]

```
def login_success():
def c1():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("c1")
    top.geometry("1000x600")


def c2():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("c1")
    top.geometry("1000x600")


def c3():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("c2")
    top.geometry("1000x600")

def write_frames():
     top = Toplevel()
     top.title("t2")
     top.geometry("1000x600")
     b1 = Button(top, text="c1", command=c1)
     b1.pack()
     b2 = Button(top, text="c2", command=c2)
     b2.pack()
     b3 = Button(top, text="c3", command=c3)
     b3.pack()

def write_instructions():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("t1")
    top.geometry("1000x600")
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x600")
button1 = Button(root,
               text="Frames",
               command=write_frames)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(root,
               text="Instructions",
               command=write_instructions)
button2.pack()
```

Comment: This question is too vague. Please show a [mcve] of what you've tried.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok I have done the changes, Please check it out, On left hand side as you can see every time a new instance is getting created, which I do not want, I want to open new window within same  main window.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pass root as a parameter to every function if i understand correctly what you mean

```
def login_success():


    def c1(root):
            top = Toplevel(root)
            top.title("c1")
            top.geometry("1000x600")


    def c2(root):
        top = Toplevel(root)
        top.title("c1")
        top.geometry("1000x600")


    def c3(root):
        top = Toplevel(root)
        top.title("c2")
        top.geometry("1000x600")

    def write_frames(root):
         top = Toplevel(root)
         top.title("t2")
         top.geometry("1000x600")
         b1 = Button(top, text="c1", command=lambda: c1(root))
         b1.pack()
         b2 = Button(top, text="c2", command=lambda: c2(root))
         b2.pack()
         b3 = Button(top, text="c3", command=lambda: c3(root))
         b3.pack()

    def write_instructions(root):
        top = Toplevel(root)
        top.title("t1")
        top.geometry("1000x600")

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("1000x600")
    button1 = Button(root,
                   text="Frames",
                   command=lambda: write_frames(root))
    button1.pack()
    button2 = Button(root,
                   text="Instructions",
                   command=lambda: write_instructions(root))
    button2.pack()
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a little, But still I have a question that a new instance is getting created, I just want that only parent window should be running and all other window's should be a child but a **new instance is getting created**. You can check my screenshot's left side every time a new process is getting created, which is getting repeated even after running your code. Should I use **root.withdraw** to close previous window's or is there any way where everything can be still done in the same instance of window.

Comment: So you want to create widgets inside this window? Root.withdraw will just hide the tk window.

Comment: Yes root.withdraw is just hiding window, I actually want to move from one frame to another but within same window. How do I do that. Every time a new window is getting open.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to do. Frames are completely irrelevant. You probably want to add widgets(button, text etc) in this window.